# Does Isomorphism $\Rightarrow$ Bijective hold in every concrete category?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, functors

Given concrete category $\mathcal{C}$, does every isomorphism (arrow) $f:X\rightarrow Y$ correspond to a bijection (function) $f:X\rightarrow Y$. I know that bijections are precisely the functions having both-sided inverse in $\operatorname{Set}$.

So basically given an iso $f$ there is its inverse $g$, then taking it by the faithful functor, we have $F(f)F(g)=F(fg)=F(id)=id_{Sset}$, and similarly from the other side, but functions having both-sided inverse are precisely bijections in $\operatorname{Set}$. Does this suffice?

Comment: What is your definition of "concrete category"?  Category with a faithful functor to Set?

Comment: Exactly that. A category equipped with a faithful functor to Set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathbf{Set}$ is any functor and $f$ is an iso in $\mathcal{C}$, then $Ff$ has inverse $F(f^{-1})$. This is an inverse in $\mathbf{Set}$, as you've noticed, and the isos in that category are precisely the bijections.

However, what I suspect you want to ask is if in every concrete category, an arrow is an iso iff its underlying morphisms of sets is an isomorphism. This is definitely not true in general (good exercise).

Comment: Asking that the structure functor is conservative ( = reflects isomorphisms) is the same as asking "iso iff bijective". It should be noted that this always hold for categories of algebras of any monad ; in particular, it holds for all varieties of algebras over a given signature.

Comment: Yeah, an easy counterexample is $Top$ where not all bijections are homeomorphisms.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, is that not what I said?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but to me it looks like you want to say that the condition "the structure functor $F$ reflects isomorphisms" implies that every bijection is an isomorphism (i.e. that one could *prove* the implication). I wanted to point out that it's *tautologically* true, because that's exactly what "reflecting isomorphisms" means.

Comment: I think you're over-analyzing this, Arnaud.

Comment: @MattCarr I think you're needlessly arguing with a very simple observation. I agree that it's potentially confusing to make claims that syntactically appear to have content but, in fact, do not, so I've edited your answer.

Comment: @KevinCarlson There was no further claim in the original post, but it seems like there was something funny about the way I phrased it that made it seem so—point taken.